# ¿Como obtener la clase(classname) y su index de un elemento, al hacer click en un segundo elemento mediante el evento onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, css, aplicación-web

```html
<table id="pan" class="w3-table-all w3-card-4">↩
<tr><th colspan='4' class='categoria'>pan y cereales</th></tr><tr> 
<th>Producto</th><th>U. de medida</th><th>Precio</th><th>Marca</th><tr 
class='w3-hover-blue'><td><div class='contenedor_prod' 
onclick='mostrar_ref(this);'><span class='referencia'>$0</span>Arroz blanco 
simple</div></td><td> 1 Kg. </td><input  type='hidden' value='1112301' 
name='codpro[]'><td><input type='number' step='0.01' min='0.01' max='99999' 
class='w3-input' name='precio[]'></td><td><input class='w3-input' type='text' 
name='marca[]'></td></tr><tr class='w3-hover-blue'><td><div 
class='contenedor_prod' onclick='mostrar_ref(this);'><span 
class='referencia'>$120</span>Facturas</div></td><td> Docena </td><input  
type='hidden' value='1111301' name='codpro[]'><td><input type='number' 
step='0.01' min='0.01' max='99999' class='w3-input' name='precio[]'></td><td> 
<input class='w3-input' type='text' name='marca[]'></td></tr></table>↩
```

Tengo un tabla que se crea dinamicamente y en una de sus columnas muestra el nombre de productos, cuestion que busco que al hacer click en dicho producto, aparezca un pequeño popup "encima" mostrando un precio de referencia y mi problema es no saber como referenciar la classname del elemento(popup)al hacer click sobre el primer elemento(productos).Edito y agrego que dicho popup solo se muestre unos 5 segundos.

aca esta el codigo de la funcion que crea el html, esta funcion se ejecuta dentro de

```
<table>function mostrar(1)</table)
```

funcion php, en la clase "contenedor_prod" es donde se deberia hacer click para que apareciera el pequeño popup de la clase "referencia"

```
{
include("conexion.php");
if($consulta = mysqli_prepare($conexion,"SELECT productos.cod_producto, productos.descripcion, productos.unidad,productos.precio_ref, rubros.descripcion FROM productos, rubros WHERE productos.rubro =? AND productos.rubro = rubros.ID_rubro ORDER BY productos.descripcion"))
{
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($consulta,'i',$numrubro);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($consulta);
  $resultado = mysqli_stmt_get_result($consulta);

}
else
{
  printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($consulta));
  die(mysqli_error($consulta)); 
}


$i=0;
$j=0;
while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
{
 if($j==0)
 { 

   echo "<tr><th colspan='4' class='categoria'>$fila[4]</th></tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<th>Producto</th>";
  echo "<th>U. de medida</th>";
  echo "<th>Precio</th>";
  echo "<th>Marca</th>";

  $j=1;
 }

  echo "<tr class='w3-hover-blue'>";
  echo "<td><div class='contenedor_prod' onclick='mostrar_ref(valorquenoconozco);' ><span class='referencia' >$$fila[3]</span>$fila[1]</div></td>";
  echo "<td> $fila[2] </td>";
  echo "<input  type='hidden' value='$fila[0]' name='codpro[]'>";
  echo "<td><input type='number' step='0.01' min='0.01' max='99999' class='w3-input' name='precio[]'></td>";
  echo "<td><input class='w3-input' type='text' name='marca[]'></td>";
  echo "</tr>";


}

}
?>
```

aqui el css del popup

```
.referencia{
padding: 10px 17px;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 12px;
background-color: rgb(66, 66, 66);
color:white;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
right:auto;
display: none;
}
```

y aqui el pequeño script de JS

```
function mostrar_ref(clase){
document.getElementsByClassName(clase).style.display= "inline-block";
}
```

NOTA: si falta complementar la pregunta, me lo hacen saber, gracias

edito y agrego el html de una de las tablas que se generan dinamicamente. Aclaro que borre parte de la tabla porque es muy extensa, pero ese seria la estructura, con datos tomados de una base de datos, copie tal cual como me salia el codigo fuente de la paginas.

```html
<table id="pan" class="w3-table-all w3-card-4">↩
    <tr><th colspan='4' class='categoria'>pan y cereales</th></tr><tr> 
    <th>Producto</th><th>U. de medida</th><th>Precio</th><th>Marca</th><tr 
    class='w3-hover-blue'><td><div class='contenedor_prod' 
    onclick='mostrar_ref(this);'><span class='referencia'>$0</span>Arroz blanco 
    simple</div></td><td> 1 Kg. </td><input  type='hidden' value='1112301' 
    name='codpro[]'><td><input type='number' step='0.01' min='0.01' max='99999' 
    class='w3-input' name='precio[]'></td><td><input class='w3-input' type='text' 
    name='marca[]'></td></tr><tr class='w3-hover-blue'><td><div 
    class='contenedor_prod' onclick='mostrar_ref(this);'><span 
    class='referencia'>$120</span>Facturas</div></td><td> Docena </td><input  
    type='hidden' value='1111301' name='codpro[]'><td><input type='number' 
    step='0.01' min='0.01' max='99999' class='w3-input' name='precio[]'></td><td> 
    <input class='w3-input' type='text' name='marca[]'></td></tr><tr class='w3- 
    hover-blue'><td><div class='contenedor_prod' onclick='mostrar_ref(this);'> 
    <span class='referencia'>$0</span>Fideos secos tipo guisero</div></td><td> 
    500g. </td><input  type='hidden' value='1113101' name='codpro[]'><td><input 
    type='number' step='0.01' min='0.01' max='99999' class='w3-input' 
    name='precio[]'></td><td><input class='w3-input' type='text' name='marca[]'> 
    </td></tr></table>↩
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo necesitas enviar el elemento en el que se hizo clic y buscar dentro el que deseas mostrar usando `mostrar_ref(this);`, donde **this** es el que hace la "magia":

```js
function mostrar_ref(item) {
  // .referencia está dentro del div (item)
  // Busca en item el elemento que contiene la clase
  let ref = item.querySelector('.referencia');
  // El click solo funcionará cuando referencia está oculto,
  // es decir, si no tiene la clase "mostrar"
  if(!ref.classList.contains('mostrar')) {
    // Agregar la clase para mostrar
    ref.classList.add('mostrar');
    // Crear una espera de 5 segundos (5000 milisegundos) para ocultar
    setTimeout(function() {
      // Quitar la clase
      ref.classList.remove('mostrar');
    }, 5000);
  }
}
```

```css
.referencia{
  padding: 10px 17px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: rgb(66, 66, 66);
  color:white;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  right:auto;
  display: none;
}
.referencia.mostrar {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<table id="pan" class="w3-table-all w3-card-4">
    <tr>
        <th colspan='4' class='categoria'>pan y cereales</th>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <th>Producto</th>
 <th>U. de medida</th>
 <th>Precio</th>
 <th>Marca</th>
    </tr><!-- Faltaba este, supongo que se te olvidó copiar -->
    <tr class='w3-hover-blue'>
        <td><div class='contenedor_prod' onclick='mostrar_ref(this);'><span class='referencia'>$0</span>Arroz blanco simple</div></td>
 <td> 1 Kg. </td>
 <input  type='hidden' value='1112301' name='codpro[]'><!-- Este debe estar dentro de un td -->
 <td><input type='number' step='0.01' min='0.01' max='99999' class='w3-input' name='precio[]'></td>
 <td><input class='w3-input' type='text' name='marca[]'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='w3-hover-blue'>
        <td><div  class='contenedor_prod' onclick='mostrar_ref(this);'><span class='referencia'>$120</span>Facturas</div></td>
 <td> Docena </td>
 <input type='hidden' value='1111301' name='codpro[]'><td>
 <input type='number' step='0.01' min='0.01' max='99999' class='w3-input' name='precio[]'></td>
 <td><input class='w3-input' type='text' name='marca[]'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='w3-hover-blue'>
        <td><div class='contenedor_prod' onclick='mostrar_ref(this);'><span class='referencia'>$0</span>Fideos secos tipo guisero</div></td>
 <td> 500g. </td>
 <input type='hidden' value='1113101' name='codpro[]'>
 <td><input type='number' step='0.01' min='0.01' max='99999' class='w3-input' name='precio[]'></td>
 <td><input class='w3-input' type='text' name='marca[]'></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Por cierto, al tener posición absoluta no hay diferencia entre usar `block` o `inline-block`.

Comment: muchas gracias, voy a estudiar y desmenuzar mas el codigo JS para entenderlo mejor, ahora bien, si no es mucha molestia, para que el mismo popup se muestre solo 5seg y regrese al estado inicial oculto?.. al poner el arroba no me permite mencionar al usuario. @Triby

Comment: Si la respuesta te sirvió, por favor márcala como aceptada. Ahora la edito para ocultar automáticamente.

Comment: Por alguna razon en mi codigo no funciona como en el ejemplo y lo unico que hice fue cambiar el "this", cambiar mi js y agregar ese fragmento de css.     @Triby

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no funciona, no aparece la referencia o no se oculta automáticamente? Revisa la consola, ¿hay algún error?

Comment: Ese es el problema, que tal cual como esta en tu ejemplo lo aplique a mi codigo, la unica diferencia es que en tu ejemplo es estatico, el mio lo genera de forma dinamica pero el resto es igual.Nose si pasar todo mi codigo completo? y en el caso de hacerlo deberia mostrarlo como "respuesta de mi pregunta?      @Triby

Comment: Desde el navegador -> ver -> código fuente, revisa que el HTML sea correcto, de ser necesario, copia todo y pégalo en el [HTML Validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input). Si aún no encuentras el error, desde ahí mismo, copia el HTML de la tabla y agrégalo en tu pregunta.

Comment: añadi un fragmento de la tabla que se genera. @Triby

Comment: A pesar de que tu HTML no es correcto, funciona. Seguramente hay algo más en tu código que impide que esto se ejecute. Revisa la consola para buscar cualquier error.

Comment: lo que me salto de incorrecto en el HTML validator era que no puedo tener un input hidden dentro de un td, no comprendo muy bien por que? pero bueno, ahora bien, si se me olvido o nose porque no se copio... dale revisare @Triby

Comment: Al menos en lo que colocaste, falta un `</tr>` y el `<input .../>` NO está dentro de un `<td>` y por eso te marca el error

Comment: probe colocando el input dentro de un `<td>` pero es lo mismo, ahora te comento, todo el html de la pagina son 400 lineas, es muy largo para mostrarlo en la pregunta , cierto?  @Triby

Comment: No es necesario que pongas todo tu HTML, con ese extracto es suficiente. Insisto, el error debe estar en otra parte, revisa la consola y asegúrate de que el script se está cargando.

Comment: debo aclarar que soy bastante nuevo en js, revise mediante el DevTool de chrome y el script se carga, la variable ref toma la clase referencia y luego la de mostrar, por eso estoy dando vueltas para encontrar cual seria el problema...

Comment: te comento que no hubo forma de que tu codigo funcione, pero use algo que aprendi con tu codigo y lo hice funcionar pero de otro modo, claro da el mismo resultado pero son distintas las lineas de codigo... nose como proceder con la pregunta ahora @Triby

Comment: Publica una respuesta con el código que te funcionó, para que pueda ser útil a otros usuarios que tengan un problema similar.